# With OData and Entity Framework, can I load navigation properties without writing getter methods for each relation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, odata

Assume we have two entities, `Parent` and `Child`, and `Child` is a navigation property of `Parent` (1:1 for the sake of this example). A particular parent's child can be fetched using this request: `http://example.com/Parent(1)/Child`. To make that work, a `GetChild()` method must be provided in the `ParentController` to fetch the correct `Child` entity.

`Microsoft.OData.Client` has a `LoadProperty` method that lets you fetch navigation properties on demand like this:

```
var parent = container.Parents.ByKey(1).GetValue();
container.LoadProperty(parent, "Child");
```

But since `LoadProperty` internally creates a `http://example.com/Parent(1)/Child` request, the call fails if I didn't write a `GetChild()` method:

> No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/navigation'.

In a project with many navigation properties it can take a lot of work to write all the getter methods. Is there a way to load navigation properties without having to write getters for every single relation?

*Edit:* I should have made clear that I'm aware of `$expand`--but sometimes it's desired to fetch related entities long after the initial request (that's what LoadProperty() does, and what requires a getter for every single relation).

Comment: Have you looked at $expand? http: //example.com/Parent?$expand=Child http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value

Answer (score 1):

OData supports [inline expansion of related entities](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398298). You can solve this problem on the client side by using the `Expand<T>` method on the object returned by `ByKey` as follows:

```
var parent = container.Parents.ByKey(1).Expand(p => p.Child).GetValue();
```

This call will result in an HTTP request similar to:

```
GET http://example.com/Parent(1)?$expand=Child
```

You can also chain calls to `Expand<T>`.

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of `$expand`. Sometimes it's desired to fetch related entities long after the initial request, though (it's what `LoadProperty()` does). But as stated in my original question, with `LoadProperty()` it's necessary to write a getter for every single relation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can modify the server-side code, you could write a custom routing convention and a base controller class to handle some or all navigation routing dynamically.

This custom routing convention handles only `GET` requests on routes of the form `~/entityset/key/navigation`, and selects actions named either `GetRelatedEntityCollection` or `GetRelatedSingleEntity` (depending on whether the navigation property references a collection or a single entity).

```
public class DynamicNavigationRoutingConvention : NavigationSourceRoutingConvention
{
    public override string SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
    {
        if (controllerContext.Request.Method != HttpMethod.Get || odataPath.PathTemplate != "~/entityset/key/navigation")
        {
            return null;
        }

        NavigationPathSegment navigationSegment = odataPath.Segments.Last() as NavigationPathSegment;
        IEdmNavigationProperty navigationProperty = navigationSegment.NavigationProperty;
        IEdmEntityType declaringType = navigationProperty.DeclaringType as IEdmEntityType;

        if (declaringType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string actionName = navigationProperty.TargetMultiplicity() == EdmMultiplicity.Many
            ? "GetRelatedEntityCollection" : "GetRelatedSingleEntity";

        if (!actionMap.Contains(actionName))
        {
            return null;
        }

        KeyValuePathSegment keyValueSegment = odataPath.Segments[1] as KeyValuePathSegment;
        controllerContext.RouteData.Values[ODataRouteConstants.Key] = keyValueSegment.Value;

        // Add information about the specific navigation property. If you need
        // more than just the name, add additional items to RouteData.Values.
        controllerContext.RouteData.Values["navigationProperty"] = navigationProperty.Name;

        return actionName;
    }
}
```

Modify your OData configuration to ensure that an instance of the custom routing convention occurs before the standard `NavigationRoutingConvention` (in order to override handling of the `~/entityset/key/navigation` route).

```
    var routingConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
    routingConventions.Insert(0, new DynamicNavigationRoutingConvention());

    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "odata",
        routePrefix: null, 
        model: model,
        pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
        routingConventions: routingConventions
    );
```

The following base controller class sketches the methods expected by the custom routing convention. Note that the `navigationProperty` parameter has the same name as one of the keys populated in `HttpControllerContext.RouteData.Values` by the routing convention.

```
public abstract class DynamicNavigationODataController<TEntity> : ODataController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetRelatedEntityCollection([FromODataUri] int key, string navigationProperty)
    {
        // Data access logic goes here. Retrieve the TEntity having the given 
        // key, and then retrieve the named navigation property.
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetRelatedSingleEntity([FromODataUri] int key, string navigationProperty)
    {
        // Data access logic goes here. Retrieve the TEntity having the given 
        // key, and then retrieve the named navigation property.
    }
}
```

You may want to change the return types of these methods to take advantage of OData's built-in query composition (i.e., `IQueryable<TEntity>` and `TEntity`, respectively).